# Certificates do not work in Docker Nginx official image

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, http-status-code-400

I have an official Nginx image in which I added certificates and the `.conf` file so it listens over port 443 and 80. I just added on Nginx official dockerfile:

```
   ADD gp-search2.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
   ADD STAR.GREY.COM.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
   ADD wildcard_grey.com.key /etc/ssl/certs/
```

I´m using Azure container instaces and I´m creating the container with this command successfully

```
az container create --resource-group RG --name nginx --image xxxxx.azurecr.io/api-s:nginx4 --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --registry-username xxxxxx --registry-password xxxxxxxxxx --ip-address public --ports 443 --dns-name-label prod3
```

After this I get a container created on azure successfully with a public IP and with the FQDN that I provided `prod3eastus.azurecontainer.io`. Also I create in *Dynect.net* a new node for the domain we have: `newcontainer.example.com` and added there the public IP of the new container so that the valid certificates I have on container are ok with than domain.

If I access the container with the public FQDN or the IP that Azure provides I can access ok, but if I try to access with HTTPS I get:

> This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 400

and

> *WARNING: cannot verify ***newcontainer.example.com*'s certificate, issued by ‘CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US’: Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.***

Even though that:

- the certificates are valid
- the certificates are on the same path that I indicate on `file.conf` in Nginx container (if not container won´t be up).

This is the `.conf` file I have:

```
upstream searchapl {


server 40.x.x.x:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;   



    }
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name _;
  #status_zone go-backend-servers;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/STAR.client.COM.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/STAR.client.COM.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://searchapl;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    # time out settings
    proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
    proxy_send_timeout   600;
    proxy_read_timeout   600;
    proxy_buffer_size    64k;
    proxy_buffers     16 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
}
```

}

This Nginx is used as a reverse proxy that redirects to a Tomcat container that is working ok. Redirection works successfully if I enter container IP. It takes me to Tomcat. But over 443 I get certificates issue. What else can I check? Certificate and key have Read Access.

---

OK Now I move forward a little step but still getting error. I created the .pem file instead of .crt whit all the chain of primary certificates and intermediate + root.

Don´t get anymore error of unable to check certificate authority but now I´m getting:

```
***--2018-08-24 21:05:05--  https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/
Resolving xxxxxxxxxxxx.com (gp_searchv2.grey.com)... 23.x.x.x
Connecting to xxxxxxxxx.com (xxxxxxxxxx.com)|23.x.x.x|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400
2018-08-24 21:05:05 ERROR 400: (no description).***
```

Comment: Please provide the needed snippets as text and not as an inlined image.

Comment: ok my bad I was having trouble to indent. It´done